# Rudin: Chapter 4, Problem 9. Rephrasing the definition of uniform continuity. Understanding a solution.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

This is from Rudin Chapter 4, problem 9:

> Show that the requirement in the definition of uniform continuity can
>   be rephrased as follows, in terms of diameters of sets: To every $\epsilon > 0$
>   there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that diam $f(E)<\epsilon$ for all $E\subset X$ with diam $E<\delta$.

Here is the solution from Baby Rudin that I'm following:

> Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on a metric space $X$. By the definition, we know that for any  $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $d(f(x), f(y))<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for any $x, y \in X$ satisfying $d(x, y)<\delta$. Thus, for all $E$ with $\text{diam}(E)<\delta$, if $x, y \in E$,then $d(x, y)≤\text{diam}(E)<\delta$, so that $d(f(x), f(y))<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. **The last inequality implies $\text{diam}(f(E))\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$**.

I don't get the last implication. Can smb explain it? Thanks.

Comment: I would place the emphasis on what comes beforehand (*i.e.*, "**for all $E$ with $\text{diam}(E)<\delta$, if $x, y \in E$, then $d(x, y)≤\text{diam}(E)<\delta$**"), especially this bit: "**if $x, y \in E$, then**". I don't know if that helps. Recall the definition of the diameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition
$$
\text{diam} (E)=\sup_{x,y\in E}d(x,y).
$$
For the proof, $\epsilon/2$ is an upper bound of the set $\{d(f(x), f(y))\mid x,y\in E\}$. But the supremum is the least upper bound whence
$$
\text{diam}(f(E))=\sup_{x,y \in E}d(f(x),f(y))\leq \epsilon/2<\epsilon 
$$